# Is there a way to recognize, that the app was installed thru firebase dynamic link in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am implementing firebase dynamic links in my iOS app and I can already parse the link, redirect to AppStore etc. Now I want to distinguish the first run of the app, when user installs it from the dynamic link - I want to skip the intro and show him the content that is expected to be shown.

Is there some parameter, that I could catch in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` so I could say that it was launched thru the dynamic link?

The method `application(_:continueUserActivity:userActivity:restorationHandler:)` is called later, so the intro is already launched.

This case is difficult to test, because you have to have your app published on the AppStore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually don't need to have the app published in the App Store for this to work — clicking a link, closing the App Store, and then installing an app build through Xcode (or any other beta distribution platform like TestFlight or Fabric) has exactly the same effect.

According to the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive#open-dynamic-links-in-your-app), the method that is called for the first install is `openURL` (no, this makes no sense to me either). The `continueUserActivity` method is for Universal Links, and is only used if the app is *already installed* when a link is opened.

I am not aware of any way to detect when the app is opening for the first time after install from a 'deferred' link, but you could simply route directly to the shared content (skipping the intro) whenever a deep link is present. If a deep link is NOT present, show the regular intro.

---

### Alternative Option

You could check out [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team). Amongst other things, Branch is a great, free drop-in replacement for Firebase Dynamic Links with a ton of additional functionality. Here is an example of all the parameters Branch returns immediately in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
{  
    "branch_view_enabled"   = 0; 
    "browser_fingerprint_id" = "<null>"; 
    data = "{  
      \"+is_first_session\":false,
      \"+clicked_branch_link\":true,
      \"+match_guaranteed\":true,
      \"$canonical_identifier\":\"room/OrangeOak\",
      \"$exp_date\":0,
      \"$identity_id\":\"308073965526600507\",
      \"$og_title\":\"Orange Oak\",
      \"$one_time_use\":false,
      \"$publicly_indexable\":1,
      \"room_name\":\"Orange Oak\", // this is a custom param, of which you may have an unlimited number
      \"~channel\":\"pasteboard\",
      \"~creation_source\":3,
      \"~feature\":\"sharing\",
      \"~id\":\"319180030632948530\",
      \"+click_timestamp\":1477336707,
      \"~referring_link\":\"https://branchmaps.app.link/qTLPNAJ0Jx\"
    }"; 
    "device_fingerprint_id" = 308073965409112574; 
    "identity_id" = 308073965526600507; 
    link = "https://branchmaps.app.link/?%24identity_id=308073965526600507"; 
    "session_id" = 319180164046538734;
}
```

You can read more about these parameters on the Branch documentation [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/advanced/ios/#branch-provided-data-parameters-in-callback).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. The firebase docs say that you can test it before it is published, but I didn't know that the process is triggered after I click the AppStore link and then run the app from Xcode. Many thanks!

Comment: I ❤️ Branch and think it's a great product, but giving a Firebase + Branch answer for a Firebase question seems a bit wrong.

Comment: Hey @NSTJ, thanks for the feedback! The OP was asking about something that is not possible to accomplish in Firebase. Hopefully they found it helpful to learn about an alternative solution 

Comment: problem is that branchio developer experience and the web interface are terrible.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... as far as I'm aware, there's not really anything you can catch in the `application:(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)` phase that would let you know the app was being opened by a dynamic link. You're going to have to wait until the `continueUserActivity` call, as you mentioned.

That said, `FIRDynamicLinks.dynamicLinks()?.handleUniversalLink` returns a boolean value nearly instantly, so you should be able to take advantage of that to short-circuit your into animation without it being a bad user experience. The callback *itself* might not happen until several milliseconds later, depending on if it's a shortened dynamic link (which requires a network call) or an expanded one (which doesn't).

Comment: This should work, though do note that on the initial install, there will still be a network call required even for an expanded link.

Comment: I also found out that the method `willContinueUserActivityWithType` is called before the launch screen disappeares. So it is the place to put the "skip intro" logic