# How to track Installs (Install Referrer) using Android firebase dynamic links?

Tags: android, firebase-dynamic-links, install-referrer

I am using firebase dynamic links in my project. It works fine with and with out installation process.

But, I want to know/implement first installation referrer ( like traditional InstallReferrer )

Using firebase dynamic links, i am getting deeplink and utm campaign parameters in both fresh install and existing app. but how to identify first installation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is currently possible using Dynamic Links. However, you can accomplish it via the [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) link platform. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40225984/5394680) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer Alex, already using Branch.io for this purpose :-) , but want to try using firebase dynamic links.

Comment: While we can use branch.io, one of the major functionalities missing is integration with adwords. We have even spoken to branch.io team and not able to solve.

Coming to the question of Firebase dynamic links, my findings are same, it doesn't pass UTM params in INSTALL_REFERRER call back. However, it still passes it in deeplink and you can write custom logic around it to read these. Definitely not the best way around, but until Firebase dynamic link does it, should serve the purpose.

Comment: @amitkankani what sort of AdWords integration were you looking for? There is a new [deep linked ad feeds](https://branch.io/deep-linked-feeds/) feature that might be relevant

Comment: @AlexBauer sure will look into it